# WSO2 support on IBM Power system

Tags: aix, wso2

Is wso2 platform supported on AIX or other operating systems on Power systems?
This particulary applies to the support of the IBM JDK. I'm getting different errors which seem to be targeted at the IBM JDK. Is the IBM JDK supported?

Thanks,

---

There are still errors i'm getting. Latest one is in BPS 2.1.2 :

> [2012-05-01 10:14:27,521]  INFO - Database - Using DAO Connection
>   Factory class org.apache.ode.dao.jpa.BPELDAOConnectionFactoryImpl.
>   Exception in thread "Attachment 33002"
>   java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: cannot get the capability,
>   performing dispose of the retransforming environment
>           at com.ibm.tools.attach.javaSE.Attachment.loadAgentLibraryImpl(Native
>   Method)
>           at com.ibm.tools.attach.javaSE.Attachment.loadAgentLibrary(Attachment.java:252)
>           at com.ibm.tools.attach.javaSE.Attachment.parseLoadAgent(Attachment.java:230)
>           at com.ibm.tools.attach.javaSE.Attachment.doCommand(Attachment.java:140)
>           at com.ibm.tools.attach.javaSE.Attachment.run(Attachment.java:101)

And another post about esb with the thrift connection also gives errors on security implementation differences in oracle/ibm

Answer (score 0):

WSO2 platform is tested on AIX. And also supports and tested with IBM jdk.

Comment: Kasun, you have a reference for that?  Most of the documentation talks about Linux/Solaris support.

Comment: There are still some problems in the version i use.
For example in BPS 2.1.2 :

Comment: Please take a look at my answer, and my other post about ESB thrift connection problem with IBM JDK!